# How do I subtract a localDate from another LocalDate

Tags: java, datetime, localdate, date-comparison

I am trying to calculate the number of days between 2 localDates

I am taking inspiration from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964 to this question [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

The trouble is, this question uses dateTime which I believe is outdated, hence the reason for using localDate.

Does anyone know of a similar way to implement the algorithm in the above answer using localDate instead.

The minus method doesn't allow subtraction of another localDate.

I have tried using

```java
ChoronoUnit.DAYS.between(LD1, LD2.plusDays(1)) //include the final day in the count
```

but there are occasions when this produces a negative number so the algorithm breaks because it chooses the smallest number as the number of days overlap

Comment: what's an "a -ve answer"?

Comment: The code example seems to be correct. What exactly do you mean by "algorithm falls over"? Your question is a little bit unclear :-)

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: If `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ld1, ld2)` returns a negative number then `ld1.isAfter(ld2)` must return true. You can easily stop getting a negative number by always making the future date be the second argument or, even more simple, just use `days = Math.abs(days)`.

Comment: It is stated in the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/ChronoUnit.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) of method `between()` in `ChronoUnit` as follows: _The result will be negative if the end is before the start._

Comment: @Abra I have read that but the thing that confuses me is that in the algorithm here <https://stackoverflow.com/a/325964> the returned answer is always positive but I can't work out what I have done wrong with my algorithm

Comment: [edit] your question and post a [mcve] demonstrating how you get a negative result.

Comment: @3rdRockSoftware In the linked answer, to paraphrase, it says: *"If start and end dates can be out of order, ... use `Min()` and `Max()`"*, as in `ChoronoUnit.DAYS.between(Math.min(LD1, LD2), Math.max(LD1, LD2)) + 1`. [Slaw's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61501388/how-do-i-subtract-a-localdate-from-another-localdate#comment108792949_61501388) is a better solution: `Math.abs(ChoronoUnit.DAYS.between(LD1, LD2)) + 1`

Comment: @Andreas I had thought of using `abs`. I'll try that and see if I can produce some sensible results

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Andreas already gave the answer in a comment: you need to take the absolute value of the day difference first, then add 1 to make the count inclusive of both start and end date.

```
public static long daysBetweenInclusive(LocalDate ld1, LocalDate ld2) {
    return Math.abs(ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(ld1, ld2)) + 1;
}
```

Let’s try it out:

```
    LocalDate ld1 = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MAY, 4);
    System.out.println(daysBetweenInclusive(ld1, LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MAY, 2)));
    System.out.println(daysBetweenInclusive(ld1, ld1));
    System.out.println(daysBetweenInclusive(ld1, LocalDate.of(2020, Month.MAY, 7)));
```

Output:

> ```
> 3
> 1
> 4
> ```

Comment: What does "then add 1 to make the count inclusive of both start and end date" mean? If I calculate the difference between a day and itself with your algorithm, I would expect to get 0 as the result and not 1. Would it mean I get 1 in the meaning of "1st day"?

Comment: @kitekat Yes, exactly. The question mentioned `include the final day in the count`. So while `ChronoUnit.DAYS.between()` takes the days from Tuesday to Thursday in the same week to be 2 (Tue and Wed), the OP wanted to include Thursday in the count to get 3. So I believe the OP also wanted the count from a day to itself to be 1, namely that day. If your requirement differs, just do not add 1.

Comment: @oleV.V. Yes that is correct. If the start day is Monday and the end day is Monday, then I needed count = 1